# android studio palette all icons are same

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My android studio palette icons are like this, is anyone know the solution ?

I try everyhing, including re install windows...

[android studio palette icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC1a9.jpg)

Comment: It's how Android Studio is designed. Can't remember about lower versions of AS but 3.2+ designed like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that this issue is related to display language settings of Windows. It was caused by Turkish language settings in my case. 
Change your Windows display language to English. Then open Android Studio, perform a clean build. Your Gradle sync will probably fail. You'll solve this by changing all `testİmplementation` to `testImplementation` in your `build.gradle(Module:app)` file.